# How can I upload a file to the Github repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a public Github repository and some files to upload in my local computer.
Using Git Bash, I ran 'git init' at the same folder that the files are located.
I also added those files using 'git add' command.
Please let me know what I should do next.
I don't know how to 'link' the local git folder and Github repository online.

Answer (score 1):

If you were able to `git add` the files, `git push` should push them to your repository on GitHub. For your first commit, you may need to `git push origin master`.

EDIT: Before you can push, you'll also need to commit the files. You can do so with `git commit -m "MESSAGE"` where MESSAGE is a brief description of what you did like "Initial import of project" or "Added files".

Comment: There needs to be a commit between adding the files and pushing to GitHub.

Comment: Good call, I'd incorrectly assumed they may have done so after the add. Edited my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already done the following:

- git init
- git add -A
- git commit -m "Initial code import"

You now setup the remote to GitHub so you can push your local branch to GitHub.

To quote GitHub:

> To connect your local repository to your GitHub account, you will need to set a remote for your repository and push your commits to it.
>
> **$** git remote add origin https://github.com/username/Hello-World.git
>
> `#` Creates a remote named "origin" pointing at your GitHub repository
>
> **$** git push origin master
>
> `#` Sends your commits in the "master" branch to GitHub

Here is the [Create A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) help guide that I quoted from.